# Input type number not working with javascript formatting function (works with input type text)

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I'm working on an interesting bug here which I have a theory about and would love some other opinions.  The issue I'm having is a javascript formatting script does not seem to be working on an input type of **number**, but it does work on an input type of text.  Working fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFME5/

In Firefox, if you just start typing in numbers in both fields, it'll auto format both as a US social security number (123-45-6789).  If you try the same in Chrome (where number type is supported), you'll see it won't work in the number text field. It basically wipes out the value when the formatting script starts writing out the hyphen.

My theory here is that the formatting script is outputting an invalid number, i.e., when it re-writes something like 123-4, it bombs out because that's not a valid floating point number.

I pretty much fleshed out this theory by keying in "123-4" in the number field, then hitting the up/down arrows in that field's chrome.  Up gives you "1", down gives "-1", so 123-4 is being treated as 0, which I'm assuming is the browser saying "nope!"

Where this is problematic for me is on mobile where, on numeric entry, I want to present a numeric keyboard (with input type=number), but that doesn't look like it's going to happen with the auto-formatting.  I'm running into the same problems with autoformatting dates with "/".  Again, assuming it's because I'm ouputting invalid numbers.

The autoformatting works fine on mobile when using input type=text, but you don't get the nicer UX keyboard feature with a numeric keyboard.  Also, input type=tel doesn't give me any problems, but then I'm assuming this is because that hyphen is valid in that context!

Has anyone run into this before? Is my theory sound?

```
FormatSSN = function(e) {
var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''), //only want numbers
    len = val.length,
    first,
    middle,
    last;

if (len > 3 && len < 6) {
    first = val.slice(0,3);
    middle = val.slice(3,5);
    this.value = first + '-' + middle;
} else if (len > 5) {
    first = val.slice(0,3);
    middle = val.slice(3,5);
    last = val.slice(5,9);
    this.value = first + '-' + middle + '-' + last;
}
};

$(document).on('keyup', '#ssn_text', FormatSSN);
$(document).on('keyup', '#ssn_number', FormatSSN);
```

Comment: You're correct. Number input fields won't allow non-number values.

Comment: use the pattern attribute to force something like /\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}/ for SSN: numbers are just that. also, type=date inputs will handle your date formatting issue on mobile.